# Check if page contains <pre> or <code> tags, if yes load files

Tags: php, html, if-statement

How to check if webpage contains `<pre>` or `<code>` using PHP and if yes include JavaScript and CSS files into it. I want to achieve something like this

```
if ( condition=true ) {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" src="prism.css" />';
   echo '<script src="prism.js"></script>';
}
```

**UPDATE**

I want to try out this for code syntax highlighting. I don't want it to be loaded on every page but only pages that contain `code`. If you are interested in this highlighter you can check their [code highlighter](http://prismjs.com)

Comment: If what webpage? What are you checking?

Comment: as the header states "if it contains `<pre>` or `<code>` tags on the page"

Comment: you want to scan your own page every time then use that to decide if you should include something? you can't come up with a better approach?

Comment: Is that page developed by you or an external page, If it yours logic is invalid, Else use DOM document

Comment: @Dagon I am newb in PHP, see my update for more info

Comment: it simply makes no sense -when you write the page to start with, you should know if you need to include the css and js

Comment: @Dagon I dont want to load these files on every page, only on pages that contain `code`. Does it make sense now?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's loaded on every page. As the lib states "it only works with <code> elements." So what's the issue?

Comment: if you want include prism.js in every pages it is not important you will use this include when needed about the css I think you can use it too just include in pages where needed and if you don't know what page it is include in all pages it is not a big deal really.

Comment: Why is this not a real question, it's perfectly clear! [tag:rov-pls].

Comment: IMHO You are doing it wrong ™. Just include in on every page and make sure the files are compressed and cached and you are done. No parsing of the document needs to happen at all. my $0.02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're focusing your effort in the wrong place. Make sure the files are both properly cached and minified, and include them on every page. The user will only download them once, and use the cached version for all further pages.

If you absolutely must,

Using PHP's DOM extension can solve this problem.

```
<?php

    $html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <code></code>

</body>
</html>
HTML;

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);

    if ($doc->getElementsByTagName("code")->length != 0) {
        $script_element = $doc->createElement("script");
        $script_element->setAttribute("src", "prism.js");

        $style_element = $doc->createElement("link");
        $style_element->setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        $style_element->setAttribute("href", "prism.css");

        $head_element = $doc->getElementsByTagName("head")->item(0);
        $body_element = $doc->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0);

        $body_element->appendChild($script_element);
        $head_element->appendChild($style_element);
    }

    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

The upside of this, is that it will inject the style and script in the correct places. Style at the head, and script at the end of `<body>`.

Comment: Thnx! but I am curious why u put code after `<html>` and where u end ur `<?php`?

Comment: @PhoxKiD: If the entire page is completely filled with PHP code (i.e. no embedded HTML code), the closing tag can be omitted. What do you mean I have code after the `<html>`?

Comment: So far best solution! also do you know how to integrate it into wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Download PHP Simple HTML DOM from

http://www.coursesweb.net/php-mysql/simple-php-html-dom_pc

extract it and put it into your project code folder and write following code :

```
include('php_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php');

// Create a DOM object from a HTML file
$html = file_get_html('test.htm');

// Write a function with parameter "$elm"
function add_css_js($elm) {
  // if pre or code tag, add css and js
  if ($elm->tag=='pre' || $elm->tag=='code') {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" src="prism.css" />';
    echo '<script src="prism.js"></script>';
  }
} 
$html->set_callback('add_css_js');
echo $html;
```

Comment: There's no need to download anything. PHP's DOM extension which is enabled by default can do it just fine.

Comment: May be you are right but when i was working and i did not put php_html_dom library in my project folder it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Output can be stored in a buffer instead of sending it directly from the script. Before sending out the content of the buffer you can modify it using a callback function.

```
<?php
// change the output before sending it out. Replace the first occurrence of <pre>
// with your html.
function callback($buffer)
{
    $str = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" src=\"prism.css\" />" .
        "<script src=\"prism.js\"></script>";
    if (strpos($buffer, "<pre>") !== false) {
        $buffer = preg_replace('/<pre>/', $str . '<pre>', $buffer,1);
    }
    return $buffer;
}

// turn on your buffer
ob_start("callback");

?>
<html>
<body>
<pre> hello </pre>
<p>It's like comparing apples to oranges.</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
// flush you content here.
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Output:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="prism.css">
    <script src="prism.js"></script>
    <pre> hello </pre>
    <p>It's like comparing apples to oranges.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score -1):

You could either use a preg_match or stristr functions.

For example:

```
$page = 'Your page content <pre>Something</pre>';

if (stristr($page,'<pre>') || stristr($page,'<code>')) {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" src="prism.css" />';
   echo '<script src="prism.js"></script>';
}
```

If by "Page" you mean the page itself then use the output buffet like this:

```
ob_start();

echo 'Your page stuff yay!';
echo '<pre>Something</pre';
echo 'End of page';

$page = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();

if (stristr($page,'<pre>') || stristr($page,'<code>')) {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" src="prism.css" />';
   echo '<script src="prism.js"></script>';
}
```

Comment: You can but you shouldn't. Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.